# Is it possible to pass the value of a parameter to an UDF constructor?

Tags: apache-pig

I've written a UDF which takes a constructor parameter.

I've successfully initialized and used it in `grunt` as

```
grunt> register mylib.jar
grunt> define Function com.company.pig.udf.MyFunction('param-value');
```

But I can't initialize it using a Pig parameter as in

```
grunt> define Decrypt com.company.pig.udf.MyFunction($secret);
```

or

```
grunt> define Decrypt com.company.pig.udf.MyFunction('$secret');
```

I tried to initialize `$secret` using both `-param` and `-param_file` options.

Are *Pig parameters* supported as UDF constructor arguments at all?

The function I'm loading is used to decrypt some data and the param-value contains special characters as "%$!" but no quotes. So I'm unsure whether I'm running into an value expansion issue or a parameter there is just not being expanded.

I'm setting the parameter value without quotes in a param file:

```
secret = My$ecr%t!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to pass parameter values to UDFs. The problem seems to be the `$` sign.

This should the correct syntax:

`define Decrypt com.company.pig.udf.MyFunction('$secret');`

In your parameter file put:

`secret=My\$ecr%t!`

The -dryrun option can be helpful for this it will create a file called `<nameofpigfile>.pig.subsituted` and not run the actual script.

`pig -x local -dryrun -f mypigfile.pig -param_file myparameterfile`

Also, you probably need pig >= 0.11

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2931